# How to concatenate index into a array variable

Tags: php

I have a array like this

**Array**

```
$array = array('Product' => array('value1','value2','value3','value4','value5'));
```

**This is Index which i want to print**

```
$index = "['Product'][3]";
```

**How to concatenate $array and $index like this**

```
$array['Product'][3];
```

**I have tried this but it is not working**

```
$array.$index;
// AND this one too
${'array'.$index};
```

**I want to output when i concatenate the index then it should give me this**

```
echo $array['Product'][3];
```

**Output**

*value4*

Comment: Your question makes little sence. Show the array that you want to create

Comment: There's no way to use variable variables for that. More versed users, who understand the repercussions, might opt for runtime interpretation. Otherwise see the linked reference for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @mario i did it `eval('echo $array'.$index.';');`

Comment: How you people have so much reputation do you work in StackOverflow or is it the best for career.